# Seeing error when I tried to update Angular CLI version in the project

Tags: angular6, angular-cli-v6

My project has the following dependencies in `package.json`.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
```

I want to use version `6.1.0` so I updated the `package.json` to following

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  }
```

But I notice an error from the IDE `The installed version didn't match version range` for few entries. I thought that if I specify new versions here then the versions will be automatically updated. Isn't that the case? How can I upgrade the dependencies?

I have `ng` installed both globally (version `6.2.1`) and locally (version `6.0.7`). Their versions are different. I want to update local to the higher version and to do this, I thought I'll just update entries in `package.json`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the correct way is to run `ng update` and that should list all the packages that need updating. As I have `ng` installed both locally and globally, if I just do `ng update`, I see message ``.

To be sure that I am updating using the local version, I use `npx ng update` to list the modules which need updating and use `npx ng update -all` to update all of them.